# Delphi TAddressBook doesn't see all contacts

Tags: android, delphi

I tested TAddressBook component from [link](https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RADStudio_Tokyo/Object%20Pascal/Multi-Device%20Samples/Device%20Sensors%20and%20Services/Address%20Book/Contacts/http://) on Delphi 10.1 Berlin (Win 8) with Android 4.2 device.

I started the program on device but didn't see contacts saved in my phone before

I can add new contacts to phone using the program but I do not see contacts made using the phone.

```
    // Fill the contact list
procedure TForm1.FillContactList(Source: TAddressBookSource);
var
  I: Integer;
  Contacts: TAddressBookContacts;
begin
  Contacts := TAddressBookContacts.Create;
  try
    AddressBook1.AllContacts(Source, Contacts);
    ListViewContacts.BeginUpdate;
    try
      ListViewContacts.Items.Clear;
      for I := 0 to Contacts.Count - 1 do
        AddListViewItem(Contacts.Items[I]);
    finally
      ListViewContacts.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    Contacts.Free;
  end;
end;
```

How to solve it?

Comment: What is your `Source` (`TAddressBookSource`)?

Comment: Yea ->  FDefaultSource: TAddressBookSource;    FillGroupList(FDefaultSource);

Comment: FDefaultSource := AddressBook1.DefaultSource;
  FillGroupList(FDefaultSource);
  FillContactList(FDefaultSource);

Comment: @Victoria- any ideas?